# <input> blur event is not firing on tablesorter "sortBegin" EVENT in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Using tablesorter I'm having an issue with the following in firefox.

The text box blur event will not always fire if I try sort emmediatly after adding text to the textbox.

Please see the code below. thanks for the help

```
// Jscript.js
$(document).ready(function () {

$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'coltwo',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell) {
        var temp = $('input', cell).val();
        return temp.replace(",", "");
    },
    type: 'text'
});
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        2: {
            sorter: 'coltwo'
        }
    }
});

//http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#Events


//update table and focus on table to try fire blur event
$("#myTable").bind("sortBegin", function () {

    $(this).focus();

    $('#myTable').trigger("update");



});


$(".txtInput").blur(function () {

    var txt = $(this).val().replace("-",""); //remove this

    $(this).val(txt + "z"); // add text to test if blur is working

});

});
```

---

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border="1"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td><input type="text" value="aaaa" class="txtInput" /></td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td><input type="text" value="bbbb" class="txtInput" /></td>  
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td><input type="text" value="cccc" class="txtInput" /></td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td><input type="text" value="dddd" class="txtInput" /></td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could try: $(document).on('blur', '.txtInput', function () { //your blur handler });

Comment: thanks but does not work

Comment: So the blur event isn't being fired at all. Then you should try it the hard way, like setting a variable with the current focused in textbox, and when the sort button is clicked, trigger the blur event manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this as a solution?

On the sortbegin event call back function then focus on a form element that is not in the table?

```
$("#myTable").bind("sortBegin", function (e, table, cell) {

    $('#myotherinput').focus();


});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the problem is that the click event on the header occurs before the blur event in Firefox and IE. So a better approach would be to detect the `keyup` event.

Also, instead of updating the entire table, use the `updateCell` method to just update the cell. You can read more about this method in my [blog post about tablesorter's missing documentation](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#methods).

Or better yet, try out the parser (code below) in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4/) which only works on my [forked version of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html). The reason it won't work on the original version is because the format `cell` argument is out of order inside of the `updateCell` method.

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'inputs',
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        var $c = $(cell);
        // return 1 for true, 2 for false, so true sorts before false
        if (!$c.hasClass('updateInput')) {
            $c
            .addClass('updateInput')
            .bind('keyup', function() {
                $(table).trigger('updateCell', [cell, false]); // false to prevent resort
            });
        }
        return $c.find('input').val();
    },
    type: 'text'
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I cannt use keyup as an event as it must be on blur. maybe I couls fite that cells inputs blur onmouse over on the header? any more ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This function is probably better/faster:

```
//bind to sort events
$("#yourtable").bind("sortStart",function() {
$(this).find('input:focus').trigger('blur');
});
```

> By the way in TableSorter 2.0 (from Christian Bach) there is no
>   "sortBegin". Instead "**sortStart**" & "**sortEnd**" is used.